# able to see code od pages in manages package

Tags: managed-package

Hi Made Managed of some pages and classes,and i installed this package in other org,i not able to see code of classes ..fine,but iam able to see code of pages,is it this,i should not see the code of pages also.Correct me if iam correct.but iam able to see code of pages,is something wrong with my code?!thanks in advance.

Comment: I did check my org with installed managed packages - I'm unable to see the code of apex classes, but I'm able to see the code of VF pages.

Comment: This is WAD. If you are worried about your JS being seen you could use this to Encode them. Pretty neat tool..http://encodejs.devincity.com

Comment: Even Google's Closure would pretty much render your JS obscure, it's all a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BSyIAM) that reffering [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging) should help you.

Long story short:

> The source of Visualforce pages is not hidden. However, the source
>   cannot be edited.

Comment: And one more thing i wanted to know,iam not able to change the api name of vf page.is there any change that i can change api name of vf page

Comment: @sasfdc - The only way to do it once it has been released would be to get deletion of managed components enabled for your DE org then delete the old page and create a new one